# jQuery .submit doesn't get called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have the following function that is meant to get called after a form I submitted (this method is in my application.js folder in my rails app):

```
var addToTopics = function() {
    var result = "";
    var checkedTopics = $(".topic-checkbox:checked");
    $.each(checkedTopics, function(i, topic) {
        if(i == 0) {
            result = result + $(topic).attr('value');
        }
        else {
            result = result + ", " + $(topic).attr('value');
        }
    });
    return result;
};


$("#new_comment").submit(function() {
    var ListOfTopics = addToTopics();
    $('#comment_topics').val(ListOfTopics);
    alert($('#comment_topics').val());
    return true;

});
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" id="new_comment" class="new_comment" action="/comments" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8"><input type="hidden" value="8vLhtuco+TAkeB+9kQ0gERvA54BD/BnjJuguWxuXWHQ=" name="authenticity_token"></div>


          <div class="field">
            <label for="comment_comment">Comment</label>
            <br>
            <textarea rows="20" name="comment[comment]" id="comment_comment" cols="40"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <input type="hidden" value="28" name="comment[review_id]" id="comment_review_id">
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="comment[user_id]" id="comment_user_id">
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <input type="hidden" value="" name="comment[topics]" id="comment_topics">
          </div>
          <div class="actions">
            <input type="submit" value="Create Comment" name="commit" id="comment_submit">
          </div>
</form>
```

But this dosen't seem to be getting called as the alert dosent even go off when I submit my form.

Any idea why? Thanks

Comment: could you please post your html file as well as the addToTopics() function as well.

Comment: @Sean Please post the rendered HTML rather than the source code.

Comment: Does your submit button have name='submit'? That would break your submit() method.

Comment: can  you post your html related to the below code $("#new_comment") // new_comment html please

Comment: Added rendered HTML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure the code attaching the listener runs after the form has been rendered to the dom. this is one way of doing it:

```
$(function() {
  $("#new_comment").submit(function() {
    var ListOfTopics = addToTopics();
    $('#comment_topics').val(ListOfTopics);
    alert($('#comment_topics').val());
    return true;
  });
});
```

Comment: That worked great thanks! Can i just ask you to explain what was going on before and how this is now fixed by adding ``$(function(){....}`` please if you dont mind? thanks

Comment: By adding the $(function() {}) wrapper, you're telling jQuery to only execute the code once the entire page has finished loading. At that point when $("#new_comment") is executed it will be able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

has an element with the id new_comment been added to the dom prior to you running $("#new_comment").submit(function(){...});

If not, then $("#new_comment") will return no selections and jquery will silently 'fail'.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then yes im sure its been loaded before. How else would I be able to submit the form if it hasn't even loded yet?

Comment: I think i now know what you mean, does the javascript file get run before the comment form is in the dom? I think it does, can i ensure that the subit function is only loaded after document is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

i had this same issue yesterday, my issue was an unrelated javascript error on the page
add a simple alert above this line

```
$("#new_comment").submit(function() {
```

to check (or check your browser js console)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing $("#new_comment").submit(function() to $("#comment_form").submit(function(), from what I'm seeing in your code those two selectors are not matching. Hope it helps. Cheers

And since you have an action attribute in your form "action='/Comment'" either remove it if you do not have a valid reason why you have it there or prevent the default behavior which will force the form to redirect to your current url + /Comment

So the code will look like :

```
$("#comment_form").submit(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    // rest of function below
});
```

Comment: I tried to chnage it to $("#comment_form") but still dosent work. However i dont understand what you mean with the action?